# Global State in Singletons

Tags: java

I was going through a talk on singletons. To begin with, here some code:

```
class AppSettings {

    private static AppSettings instance = new AppSettings();

    private Object state1;
    private Object state2;
    private Object state3;

    private AppSettings() {}

    public static AppSettings getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

The speaker says that since `instance` is static, it is a global variable and whatever is accessible using `instance` will also have global state.

Can someone explain to me what global state means? I know that global state is accessible throughout the application, and can be changed by another objects which is bad. But how does declaring `instance` as `static` make it global?

Comment: As there will be only one instance of the AppSettings object (as it is a static variable), the state member fields which can be accessed through this instance by any other object (Of course you need getters and setters for these members as they are private). Hence they can be used for maintaining global states

Comment: Oh, so since there's only one instance of this class, only that state is available globally, right. If changes are made to this object, every object that is using it will see that changes. Got it.

Comment: Could you add this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there will be only one instance of the AppSettings object (as it is a static variable), the state member fields which can be accessed through this instance by any other object (Of course you need getters and setters for these members as they are private). Hence they can be used for maintaining global states

Answer (score 2):

"global" is the wrong term for that. The variable `instance` is still only visible inside the `AppSettings` class. However the `AppSettings` instance referenced by it is made available to the outside world via the `getInstance` method.

Comment: Also, it means that any thread and object can access both the instance and the objects and values references directly and indirectly by the instance.